# For a WPF application, what files do I need to share the source code?

Tags: c#, wpf

Having created a WPF/C# demo application (in Visual C# Studio Express), what are the minimum files  I would need to zip up, to give the source to someone? (*Not* deploy an executable, but enough actual source code to recreate the project).

Obviously I need the `*.xaml *.cs *.sln *.csproj` files.

Do I need `*.suo *.csproj.user`, or are those specific to my editor?

Do I need any or all of the files in the `Properties` directory? Some of those files say *auto-generated*, which would seem to imply they're not needed.

Comment: Any reason not to include everything other than the bin and obj folders?

Comment: You don't need any .suo or .user, but you want properties files.  I'm adding this as a comment since it's not an exhaustive list.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone, I guess I could, I doubt there's any confidential information in them, just I tend to prefer having only necessary files in a zip.

Comment: There is no confidential information in them. Go ahead, delete those folders and zip away.  You can also use "Clean" on the build menu to clean them up before zipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd share the `Properties` files as well, it generally being a good idea to share and version all files that are needed to compile the project regardless of the IDE. Since it's an IDE tool that generates those files, I'd consider it bad form to leave them out, in case you want to set up a Continuous Integration server or something of that sort.

The `*.suo` files are Solution **User** Options, which kind of implies that they're per-user, not per-project. Same goes for the `*.user` files.

Answer (score 1):

the *simplest* thing is to delete any obj/bin directories (if they exist), and just zip up everything else.

the .user and .suo are things that will get recreated, but there's no harm in sending them (unless they are really big!)

That being said, it *really* depends on the details of your project, and how you have it organized.